# Multiple images in a ttk label widget

Tags: python, tkinter, label, ttk

With ttk labels, it is possible to specify multiple images which are displayed according to the label's state. But I can't make it work. Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

BITMAP0 = """
#define zero_width 24
#define zero_height 32
static char zero_bits[] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
};
"""

BITMAP1 = """
#define one_width 24
#define one_height 32
static char one_bits[] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
};
"""

root = Tk()
img0 = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP0, foreground='lime', background='black')
img1 = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP1, foreground='lime', background='black')
label = Label(root, image=(img0, 'active', img1))
label.pack()
```

The label is 'active' when the mouse pass over it. So the displayed digit should switch from a 0 to a 1 when the mouse passe over it. But it doesn't work.
Any help ?
Python 3.5.1 / Windows Vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the docs a bit confusing but it looks like you want `'hover'` instead of `'active'`.

I am not aware of any source explaining which state flags are automatically set in which wigdets in which conditions. What I did here was to place the mouse cursor over the label and then query the state by calling `label.state()`.

Comment: The list of states for ttk widgets is here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-map.html and the documentation of image option for ttk.Label widget is here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Label.html

Comment: @Jal I should have written "reliable and complete sources". But did using `'hover'` instead of `'active'` work for you?

Comment: No, `hoover` seems not to be a valid ttk widget state _tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name hoover. There is a workaround to my problem using `label.bind("<Enter>", enter)` and `label.bind("<Leave>", leave)` but I would like to understand why `Label(root, image=(img0, 'active', img1))` doesn't work as expected. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Jal It's not `'hoover'` but `'hover'`.

Answer (score 0):

The ttk.Label does not appear to accept states. However, enter/exit binding does work with style configure setting.  Output is 0/1 in green.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def Limg1(*args):
  s.configure('zL1.TLabel', image=img1)

def Limg0(*args):
  s.configure('zL1.TLabel', image=img0)

root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use("classic") #3D/Color-alt/classic/default, Color-clam). 

BITMAP0 = """
#define zero_width 24
#define zero_height 32
static char zero_bits[] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f, 0xf0,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f,
0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0xf0,0x3c,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
};
"""

BITMAP1 = """
#define one_width 24
#define one_height 32
static char one_bits[] = {
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f,
0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x0f, 0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
};
"""

img0 = tk.BitmapImage(data=BITMAP0, foreground='lime', background='black')
img1 = tk.BitmapImage(data=BITMAP1, foreground='lime', background='black')

s.configure('zL1.TLabel', image=img0)

label = ttk.Label(root, style='zL1.TLabel')
label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew');

label.bind('<Enter>',Limg1);
label.bind('<Leave>',Limg0);
root.mainloop()
```